# IValueConverter get wrong culture in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, globalization, cultureinfo

I created a value converter in my Windows Phone 7 ...

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ... 
}
```

... and use it like this ...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeField, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=SomeParameter}" <!-- ... --> />
```

My problem: The `argument` culture of the Convert method is always "en-US", even when I change the culture of the Windows Phone device (or emulator) say to german Germany, the `culture` argument stays english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug, intended behaviour. See this post on MSConnect [WPF Binding uses the wrong CurrentCulture by default](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/442569/wpf-binding-uses-the-wrong-currentculture-by-default).

The solution is to set the `Language` property of your `PhoneApplicationPage` to the CurrentCulture, like this:

```
Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
```

Or alternatively specify the culture in XAML, using the `Language` attribute, like this:

```
<TextBlock Language="de-DE" Text="..." />
```

Or on the `PhoneApplicationPage` it self

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage Language="de-DE" ...
```

But a much better solution is not to have a value-converter that's depending on the `culture` argument.

**Edit:** I blogged about a alternative solution: [DateTime formatting in a ValueConverter](http://windcape.posterous.com/datetime-formatting-in-a-valueconverter)

Comment: Your first suggestion sounds good to me, should I place it in the constructor of my Page or in a event called later?

Comment: In the constructor. Otherwise you risk it not being applied in a timely fashion.

Comment: Ok, but now culture argument is "de", not "de-DE", what results in an IndexOutOfRange exception when I use it in any .Format method (tried DateTime and String) ...

Comment: Right. Try the `Name` property instead of `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` if you need sub-cultures as well. But again, I would **strongly** encourage not to have culture dependant code in a converter.

Comment: Ok, now it is working, thanks. If you encourage not having culture dependant code in a converter, how would you bind a TextBlock to a DateTime and make it format the output as a short date of the current culture? I'm just beginning with Silverlight and WP7 so I'm willing to learn here ...

Comment: ValueConverters are meant to always convert the same way, so you could write a converter that takes the format as a parameter, and then bind the converterparameter to a (static) resource (binding). Or you could do the date-time formatting in your viewmodel (best approach in my opinion).

Comment: @Hinek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2572/discussion-between-claus-jorgensen-and-hinek)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking up the [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Might be a bug in WP7 where that isn't being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem.

I solved it using the following:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{   
    return string.Format(culture, "{0:N}, value);   
}
```

Use culture to convert control the conversion, but you must also make sure you leave the value parameter as an object.  Changing it's type affects how the string.Format interacts with it.

Comment: Sorry, but how does that solve the problem of culture containing the wrong value (en-US instead of the culture configured in the phone settings)?

Comment: Ah - sorry. This might help. it describes this problem and a work-around:  http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/88151.aspx